# map<Key,pair<A,B>> to map<Key,A>

Tags: c++

I have a class that for some reasons needs to store a pair (say int,double) for each key, but whose interface only makes public one of the two values of the pair (int). One implementation may be

```cpp
using namespace std;
class Foo {
public:
  map<string,int> const & get() const {return external;}
  void doStuff(string const & str) {
    external.at(str);
    internal.at(str);
  }
private:
  map<string,int> external;
  map<string,double> internal;
};
```

The drawback is that doStuff has double lookup.

Another way is to store `map<string,pair<int,double>> allin` but then the accessor returning the whole map requires a copy.

The last way, of course, is to make the accessor more atomic by accessing a single key with a `return allin.at(key).first;`, which seems the best way but it breaks the interface I would like to provide.

I wonder, is there a way to avoid the double lookup in the "external/internal" version?

Comment: You don't want as an interface to return "exactly map<X,Y>", you want to return something that satisfies such and such concepts.

Comment: you are so right. With some (lot?) work in developing this "something" and an auto on the client side, nobody will see the difference.

Comment: If you can modify the map declaration, you don't need to use a pair. Instead, use a `struct { int x; private: double y; }` and `friend` whatever you need to use that private value. Make the struct convertible to `int` and noone will be able to tell. It's not necessarily a good way, but it's a way.

Comment: am I wrong or this something, in the end, should belong to c++20 standard "range/view"  stuff?

Comment: ranges are about sequences, while this is about property maps. There are some similarities, but the concepts are quite different.

Answer (score -1):

Another way could be to define a map entry with a private and a public value. Via a friend declaration the private value can be made visable to Foo class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

class Foo;
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct my_map_entry
{
    public:
        my_map_entry()=default;
        my_map_entry(T1 v, T2 pv)
        {
            value = v;
            private_value = pv;
        }
        T1 value;
    private:
        T2 private_value;
        friend class Foo;
};

class Foo {
    public:
        Foo(){
            map["test"]=my_map_entry<int, double>(1, 2.0);
        }
    
        void doStuff(const std::string& str
        {
            auto entry = map.at(str);
            std::cout<<"private_value: "<<entry.private_value<<std::endl;
        }
    
        std::map<std::string,my_map_entry<int, double>> map;
};

int main()
{
    Foo test;
    test.doStuff("test");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Given you just want the user to be able to retrieve the item, your get() method can be rewritten bearing that requirement in mind.

```
using namespace std;
class Foo {
public:
  int *const get(string const &str) const {
    auto it = map_.find(str)
    return it == map_.end() ? nullptr : &it->first;
  }

  void doStuff(string const & str) {
    map_.at(str);
  }
private:
  map<string,pair<int, double>> map_;
};
```

The idea is to return nullptr if the key was not found, or a pointer to the value if the key was found.

If instead you also want to be able to enumerate all the available ints, then you only have three choices:

1. Make your Foo class a map-like class, with its own iterators that wrap the ones from the inner map.
2. Use one of the available libraries to provide a view that helps you achieving the previous goal (like [boost::transform_iterator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html))
3. As the other answer suggests, use a struct as the map's value and make one of its fields private, with possibly a conversion operator to int.

Comment: Looks like somebody had fun downvoting the question and the answers here. What a nice way to pass time, uh?